# SQL to insert into table from two tables in ascending order

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a need to create a table that maps two table values. There are no keys that can be used to join these tables but it is guaranteed that the number of rows in these two tables are guaranteed to be the same and lowest ID value in one maps to the lowest in other all the way to the highest. The actual ID itself will be different in the two tables

Is there a way to do this in SQL Server.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SQL Server 2005+:

```
WITH Table1Ranked AS (
  SELECT
    ID,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID)
  FROM Table1
),
Table2Ranked AS (
  SELECT
    ID,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID)
  FROM Table2
)
INSERT INTO MapTable (Table1ID, Table2ID)
SELECT t1.ID, t2.ID
FROM Table1Ranked t1
  INNER JOIN Table2Ranked t2 ON t1.rn = t2.rn
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use Dense_Rank function in your case.

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
    ID      INT,
    NAME    VARCHAR(10)
)

CREATE TABLE Table2
(
    ID      INT,
    NAME    VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO Table1
SELECT 1, 'abc'
UNION
SELECT 2, 'def'

INSERT INTO Table2
SELECT 3, 'abc'
UNION
SELECT 4, 'def'

SELECT tbl1.ID AS [ID1]
    , tbl1.NAME AS [Name1]
    , tbl2.ID AS [ID2]
    , tbl2.NAME AS [Name2]
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, NAME
        , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS [Rank]
    FROM Table1
) as tbl1
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT ID, NAME
            , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS [Rank]
        FROM Table2
    ) as tbl2 ON tbl1.[Rank] = tbl2.[Rank]
```

It may Help you.

Answer (score 0):

If (and only if) you know that both sets of IDs go up evenly, e.g. both start at a certain number and always go up by 1, then just select @offset = lowest in one minus lowest in other. Then just use the offset to join.